# Save all column names and its index pairs as a dataframe/dictionary

Tags: r, dataframe

I tried to get column names and its index, and save the result as a dataframe or dictionary:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10), b=rnorm(10), c=rnorm(10))
```

How could I do that? Thanks.

```
column index
a   1
b   2
c   3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
data.frame(column = colnames(df), index = seq_along(df))
#   column index
# 1      a     1
# 2      b     2
# 3      c     3
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
library(tibble)

enframe(names(df), "index", "column")

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  index column
  <int> <chr> 
1     1 a     
2     2 b     
3     3 c
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `tidyverse` option:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("index") %>% 
  select(name, index)
```

**Output**

```
  name  index
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     1    
2 b     2    
3 c     3
```